# How to get GitLab CI variables into the Sinatra app to query Google Cloud Datastore?

Tags: ruby, environment-variables, google-cloud-datastore, gitlab-ci

Short:
I want to be able to deploy a Sinatra app without hardcoded secrets and variables using Google Cloud App Engine. Deploying to App Engine while ensuring the environment variables get loaded from the Google Cloud Datastore was the suggested option. I hoped to find something similar to the simplicity of Heroku, but this is not the case.

Question:
How would I get the $SERVICE_ACCOUNT environment information (that I've set in the GitLab CI / CD section) as the credentials value in `foobar.rb`?

app.yaml:

```
image: google/cloud-sdk:latest

before_script:
  - apt-get install -y ruby-full build-essential
  - gem install bundler
  - bundle config --global silence_root_warning 1
  - bundle install

after_script:
  - rm /tmp/$CI_PIPELINE_ID.json

deploy_production:
  stage: deploy
  environment: Production
  only:
    - production
  script:
    - echo $SERVICE_ACCOUNT > /tmp/$CI_PIPELINE_ID.json
    - gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file /tmp/$CI_PIPELINE_ID.json
    - gcloud --quiet --project $PROJECT_ID app deploy app.yaml
```

foobar.rb:

```
...
require "google/cloud/datastore"

class App < Sinatra::Application
  if settings.production?

    data_store = Google::Cloud::Datastore.new(
      project: 'foobar',
      credentials: "???"
    )

    query = data_store.query "kindoffoobar"
    results = data_store.run query

    # Set each result as an env variable
    results[0].properties.to_h.each do |key, value|
      ENV[key]= value
    end
  end

... rest of app
```

Comment: does this answer help at all? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43226786/google-cloud-functions-environment-variables

Comment: gave up and decided to have the env variables in the app.yaml file before deploying and not commit them.