# How do I make Environment Variables available globally across all Cloud Functions by using Google Cloud Console / Firebase Console?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, environment-variables

Here is the example of my Environment Variables as seen in the Google Cloud Console => Cloud Functions:

[image]

But now I had to declare this in EACH Cloud Functions, thus this is not scalable when I got many functions.

I saw an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43226786/google-cloud-functions-environment-variables) But the solution suggested here is not using Google Cloud console or Firebase console and it seems outdated. There could be an update.

Does anyone knows how to make the Environment Variables available globally within a project by using Google Cloud console / Firebase console?
And if that is not possible, is there a way to create these variables automatically somehow?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no global environment variables with Cloud Functions.  Each function is fully isolated from each other in terms of configuration and deployment.

You could instead query a database shared by all your functions with some sort of global config.

Comment: Thanks Doug you are always fast to respond and a life saver. ;-)